# 4 linear equations in 4 variables with complex coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Here $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are distinct complex numbers, $k$ a complex variable.

I want to show that the following system of linear equations in variables $a,b,c,d$ has a nontrivial solution.

$az_1 + b -cz_1 -d = 0$

$az_2 + b +cz_2 +d = 0$

$az_3 + b -kcz_3 -kd = 0$

$az_4 + b +kcz_4 +kd = 0$

I tried putting the coefficients in a matrix, computing the determinant, and simplifying to get:

$2k((z_3 - z_2)(z_1-z_4) + (z_3 - z_1)(z_2 - z_4)) + (k^2 + 1)(z_4 - z_3)(z_1 - z_2).$

But i'm not sure how to show this quantity is nonzero.

Comment: This is a homogeneous system, it has a solution $(0,0,0,0)$. Do you want a non-trivial solution?

Comment: Yes please, the nontrivial I should've mentioned, thank you, just editted.

Comment: Then you should prove that determinant is equal to zero, not that it is non-zero. If determinant is non-zero, then you have a unique solution, and it must be $(0,0,0,0)$.

Comment: Ah. I just realized that $k$ is a free variable. So since I arrived at a quadratic expression in $k$. We know it has roots by the FoA, and so we are done. Is this correct?

Comment: Is the problem: For given $z_i$'s, show that there exists $k$ such that the system has a non-trivial solution? If so, then yes, you can see the determinant as a polynomial in $k$, and it has zero in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Yes, great thank you.